# Smooth Horizontal Scrolling of Recyclerview inside Scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve an effect like the landing page of Google Play store. What I believe is, the hierarchy is as follows -

- CoordinatorLayout
- ScrollView
- Recyclerview with Horizontal Linearlayout

The Horizontal swipe on the "New+Updated Games" section is incredibly smooth, and does not interfere with vertical scrolling. In my implementation, during swipe, there is a movement up and down, and thus the effect is not smooth.

Ideally only for explicit UP or DOWN gestures, should the view go up or down.

Is my understanding correct? Is there any tutorial or guide that helps me achieve the same effect?

[image]

Comment: i have same issue. did you find any solution?

Comment: I am also stuck

Answer (score 1):

I would really appreciate if you could add some code snippets for a better understanding of your problem.. Albeit, here's an excerpt

```
{
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(), arrayList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false); the last parameter sets ReverseLayout to false so you dont need to set true then false.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly you got scrollview as parent and you have a child recyclerview with horizontal scroll/swipe whatever so simply do this on your recyclerview.

```
addOnItemTouchListener(new OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING){
                    recyclerView.stopScroll();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {

            }
        });
```

If you got more then 1 recyclerview do the same with other recyclerviews. And if this helps don't forget to upvote

Answer (score 0):

**ViewPager**

Hi,

I don't think you required to use Recyclerview, I suggest you please use View Pager to achieve the feature. It will solve your problem.